# Setting a default value in drop down field using JQuery on document load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to set a default value in a drop down field when the page is loaded. However i am unable to set the value. I have tried the same for another field it works fine. Below are the HTML codes for the field for which it works fine and JQuery code as well.

HTML Codes:

```
<div class="form-field select required request_type">
<label for="request_type">Type</label>
<a class="nesty-input" tabindex="0">Problem</a>
<select id="request_type" name="request[type]" style="display: none;">
<option value="-">-</option>
<option value="question">Question</option>
<option value="problem">Problem</option>
</select>
<p>Request type</p>
</div> 
<div class="form-field string required request_custom_fields_21062749">
<label for="request_custom_fields_21062749">Severity</label>
<input id="request_custom_fields_21062749" type="hidden" name="request[custom_fields][21062749]" data-tagger="[{"label":"-","value":""},{"label":"Low","value":"lowsev"},{"label":"Medium","value":"mediumsev"},{"label":"High","value":"highsev"},{"label":"Critical","value":"criticalsev"}]" autocomplete="off" value="mediumsev">
```

Medium

Jquery:

```
var severityId =21062749;
$(document).ready(function() {
    var ct_tags = HelpCenter.user.tags; 
    if(location.pathname == "/hc/en-us/requests/new" || location.pathname == "/hc/en-us/requests") { 
        if(ct_tags == "product"){
            $('select#request_type').val("problem");// This value is displayed in the form
            $('select#request_custom_fields_'+severityId).val("mediumsev");//This value is not displayed.
        }
    }
});
```

Regards,
Shaik.

Comment: `$('select#request_custom_fields_'+severityId)` So what is `severityId` value???  BTW, looks like you are targeting hidden input, so how do you check value??? How do you expect this vlaue to be displayed??? And anyway, default value for this input is the same as the one you are trying to set. PLEASE, improve your question!

Comment: `request_custom_fields_21062749` isn't a `<select>`, it's an `<input>`.

Answer (score 0):

in this way it will be set:

`$(document).ready(function() {
$('#request_custom_fields_21062749').val("meddfiudfgdjlfgmsev");
});`

so I Ithink in your if statement is an mistake!